# Chain Gulp glob to browserify transform

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob, browserify

I have a project with a few relatively disjoint pages, each including their own entry point script. These scripts `require` a number of others using commonjs syntax, and need to be transformed by 6to5 and bundled by browserify.

I would like to set up a gulp task that captures all the files matching a pattern and passes them on to the bundler, but I'm not sure how to pass files from `gulp.src` to `browserify(filename)`.

My gulpfile looks like:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var to5browserify = require("6to5-browserify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");

var BUNDLES = [
    "build.js",
    "export.js",
    "main.js"
];

gulp.task("bundle", function () {
    /* Old version, using glob:
    return gulp.src("src/** /*.js")
        .pipe(sixto5())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
    */

    // New version, using array:
    return BUNDLES.map(function (bundle) {
        return browserify("./src/" + bundle, {debug: true})
            .transform(to5browserify)
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source(bundle))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
    });
});

gulp.task("scripts", ["bundle"]);

gulp.task("html", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*.html")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task("styles", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/**/*.css")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task("default", ["scripts", "html", "styles"]);
```

This seems to work, but isn't maintainable: I'll be adding more scripts relatively soon, and don't want to add them to the array every time.

I've tried using `gulp.src(glob).pipe` within the browserify call and piping after calling ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697306/es6-transpiler-browserify-gulp?rq=1)), and `gulp.src(glob).map` (method doesn't exist).

How can you chain `gulp.src` with a name-based transformer like browserify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) to make a one-off custom plugin stream that does all of the dirty work.

Unfortanately [`vinyl-transform`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-transform) and [`vinyl-source-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) and the solutions that go along with those have flaws so we have to go for something custom.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through = require('through2');
var browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    var browserified = function() {
        return through.obj(function(chunk, enc, callback) {
            if(chunk.isBuffer()) {
                var b = browserify(chunk.path);
                    // Any custom browserify stuff should go here
                    //.transform(to5browserify);

                chunk.contents = b.bundle();

                this.push(chunk);

            }
            callback();
        });
    };

    return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(browserified())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: This seems awfully close, but I'm having a problem getting 6to5 involved. Using your code but adding the `.transform()` call before `.bundle()` causes a "write after end" error. I tried adding the `{read: false}` option to the `gulp.src` call, but that caused my dist dir to be empty.

Comment: Using `pipe(through.obj())` gets rid of the "write after end" error, but the output file is browserified *but not 6to5-ified*.

Comment: After the edits (and some time spent in chat), this seems to have solved the issue. It feels like a little bit of a hack, but seems to work well (locally and in CI).

Answer (score -2):

You can specify globs in your BUNDLES array as well as exclude any files:

```
var BUNDLES = [
    "app/**/*.js",
    "export.js",
    "app/modules/**/*.js",
    "!app/modules/excluded/*.js"
];
```

Comment: This simply throws an error `Cannot find module 'src/**/*.js'` when it encounters the glob on the way into browserify.