# Gulp + browserify example (without gulp-browserify)

Tags: gulp, browserify

Now that [gulp-browserify is no longer supported](https://github.com/deepak1556/gulp-browserify) I am looking for a simple tutorial how to now use browserify with gulp. [This](http://fettblog.eu/gulp-browserify-multiple-bundles/) seems like an option, but it's still quite complex. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Also looking for this. Just want the simplest way to configure gulp & browserify to take a bunch of JS files in one folder, and combine them all into a single public application.js file.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441837/5708926)

With respect to the linked post the code will change to

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var through2 = require('through2');
var rename     = require('gulp-rename');
var browserify = require('browserify');

function browserified() {
    return through2.obj(function(file, enc, next) {
        browserify(file.path, {
                debug: false
            })
            .plugin(collapse)
            .bundle(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }

                file.contents = res;
                next(null, file);
            });
    });
}

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./app/main-a.js', './app/main-b.js'])
        .pipe(browserified())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.bundle.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to use watchify right away (sooner or later you will need to watch javascript files for changes). Please see this example:

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./src/index.js'],
  debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts)); 

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
  return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
       // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}
```

The example is taken from [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md)
More useful examples can be found [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes).

Answer (score 0):

The best I could find is this video:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-gulp-and-browserify-initial-setup

Here is the most succinct code snippet (with some comments) I could come up with for your gulpfile.js (which you can/should(?) put in the same folder as your npm package.json file):

```
"use strict";

// you have to install each of these via npm install,
// and add them to your package.json file
// eg npm install gulp --save [or --save-dev]
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

// once you've installed gulp globally, you can run gulp tasks like:
// gulp name-of-task
// if you make name-of-task 'default', then just running
// gulp
// will run it
// if you install gulp only locally, you'll need to add to your 'scripts' block
// in package.json eg
// 
// "scripts": {
//     "gulp": "gulp",
//     ...[other scripts go here]...
// }
// and run like:
// npm run gulp (or whatever you named it)
gulp.task('[name-of-task]', function() {
    return browserify('[path to entry file for app *relative to the location of the gulpfile.js*]')
        // bundle is a function of the browserfy API
        .bundle()
        // I'm honestly a little baffled, I'm not sure where 'pipe' is documented...
        // vinyl-source-stream ('source') also a little unclear on that one
        .pipe(source('[name of the bundled js file]'))
        // gulp.dest writes files for you
        .pipe(gulp.dest('[path to where to write the bundled js file, again relative to location of gulpfile.js]'))
});
```

Hth someone, I got stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

[Gulp offers some answers in its repo](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md).

I got out with this code in the `gulpfile.babel.js`:

```
// Package
import fs from 'fs';
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));

// Gulp
import gulp from 'gulp';
import addSrc from 'gulp-add-src';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify-es';

// Misc
import babelify from 'babelify';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
```

And then:

```
export function scripts() {

    const src = pkg.settings.src.scripts;

    const bundler = browserify({
        entries: src,
        debug: true,
        transform: [babelify]
    });

    const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, pkg.settings.out.assets);

    const assets = [
        './node_modules/...'
    ]

    return bundler.bundle()
        .pipe(source(src))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
        .pipe(addSrc.prepend(assets))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat(pkg.name + '-' + pkg.version + '.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath));
}
```

I also have a `.babelrc` with:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

The tricky part here is to avoid to forget the 'vinyl-source-stream' and 'vinyl-buffer', so you can manipulate the stream and vinyl format from the browserify bundle.

Also note that I consider having only two different 'types' of js modules: *my* modules, imported in the main src file that I give to browserify ; and all the *external* modules and dependencies, that I manage with NPM and specify in an `assets` array here.